# Do we really need [max] and [min]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

The description for [max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/max) reads:

> Maximum value. Largest, biggest, greatest.

and that for [min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/min) is:

> Minimum value. Smallest, tiniest, least.

Those have 2488 and 682 questions respectively and 11 and 1 followers.

Do these tags serve much purpose?  [min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/min), [max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/max) do not appear useful for searching either and I'm not sure how would one determine expertise in these tags given the variety of contexts in which these could appear.

Comment: May I had that these concepts are exactly symmetric?

Comment: They are context tags for [sql] questions.  Gordon Linoff is the resident expert.  Not so sure why it is important to zap them, but you ought to ask Gordon.

Comment: @HansPassant maybe that was their intended use, but their actual use has little to do with sql - there's only two sql questions in the first page of results for `max` atm.

Comment: The are low volume tags, sitting on the long tail of SO, so that's hardly surprising.  Still, Gordon has answered 117 questions about them.  The long tail is important, not every question has a "just use jQuery" answer.

Comment: Those tags should be merged

Comment: It helps experts find questions to answer, for example I am experienced in all things [min] but don't really dabble in [max].

Comment: For the record, [median], [average] and [mode] exist as tags, too. Most [mode] questions are not related to the statistical concept of mode, but some are.

Comment: The wiki excerpts are terrible (Either the maximum or minimum may have the largest magnitude, and the smallest values are often neither maximal nor minimal, in signed number systems)

Comment: @WesleyMurch What's the difference? A problem with `max` is the negative of a problem with `min`.

Comment: @becko I have a gold badge in [sarcasm].

Comment: There is also a tag [sam], so presumably we can have [sam] 'n [max] questions! The large ball of twine, that was a difficult task.

Comment: @becko Perhaps, but it should be noted that `[minmax]` is a separate topic, in which someone certainly can be an expert.

Comment: I think they are useful in SQL aggregate functions realm.

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't. They are yet another useless tag that nobody follows like `select`. Maybe a general `sql-aggregate` tag might be all right to help people find questions but I don't think each aggregate needs its own tag.

Comment: So can we start burninating these yet then? The whole burninate process seems a bit broken to me, not really clear when the opinion is sufficiently "for" for these to be actioned.

Comment: @MartinSmith It seems that we already have one.  [aggregate-functions] (x1687)

Answer (score 61):

At the risk of having my head chopped off, I've read other burninate requests and the most common thing is "can you be an expert in it?"

I fail to see how one can be an expert in finding the minimum or maximum of a set. Or if you can, then you must really have low goals...

I see other answers saying things like "well it's not so easy is some languages", but in that case you would be an expert in the *language* to know how to do min/max in said language.

Therefore, my opinion is to burninate the [min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/min) and [max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/max) tags.

Comment: Yes, a generic min, max tag doesn't make much sense.  Maybe _complex_ languages, can choose custom _min/max_ (or even other statistical variants).

Comment: @devnull And even then, do we need *two* tags? `extremum` would be more... efficient. But we'd then have to have `min` and `max` as tag synonyms for it otherwise nobody would know what that word means XD

Comment: I don't feel the need of having those language-specific variants either.  Just mentioned that because there seem to be many that find these _useful_.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Discoverability is important too, otherwise they'd never get used.  If we do decide to keep them, [tag:min-max] is far better than [tag:extremum]

Comment: "I fail to see how one can be an expert in finding the minimum or maximum of a set." Have a talk with [axiomatic set theor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem)eticians on math.SE ;) But it's true, that's (currently?) beyond the scope of possibilities of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Izkata: that's easily confused with [minimax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimax).

Comment: @Rhymoid, those concepts are simple even in axiomatic set theory and order theory. Yes, newcomers get confused about the smallest/minimal/infimum and greatest/maximal/supremum distinctions, but they are ultimately simple concepts. They're also rarely important for computer *programming*, although they show up all the time in computer *science*.

Comment: Speaking about `min` and `max` as just the smallest / largest number of a small set, yes there isn't much to it. But don't underestimate the whole optimization part of mathematics. The objective function usually is just a `min` or a `max` and it's the exact opposite of easy. Oh, and by the way: The problems with a finite set are usually  even harder. So, one can indeed be an expert in `min`/`max`, but the tag should be something like optimization to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: There is an `optimization` tag.  There are experts in optimization generally and for specific purposes.  Min and max are merely a sign change away from being duplicates and add nothing. Burn um.

Answer (score 32):

No. Given that these are statistics easily generated using base functionality in most programming languages, I cannot see how these are valuable tags.

Comment: Yet people struggle with the concept of calculating both the min and max for a generator, for example.

Comment: There's a big flaw here. What you meant to say is that it's not valuable *to an experienced* developer. Based on your argument, we could easily wipe out 95% of the site.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it's not valuable for getting answers. If someone wants to implement `max` in a language, tagging the language and using an appropriate title will suffice. Tagging or not tagging with `max` will not influence the question getting answered in the slightest. Thus it effectively becomes noise as I'd expect it to be in the title anyways...

Comment: @l4mpi That's correct, but the argument in the answer here is not really applicable

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret this, you want them burned right?

Comment: @l4mpi you can say the same thing about [garbage-collection] or any other generic programming concept. If I have a [Java] [garbage-collection] question, I doubt a C# programmer could help me.

Comment: @ajacian81 That depends. If you have a question about a specific implementation of garbage collection in C# or Java, you will of course need someone who knows the specific implementation. This also differs between implementations of one language, e.g. someone who knows the CPython GC can't help you with questions about the PyPy GC. But GC questions can also stand on their own, e.g. you could ask about a specific GC scheme or your own GC implementation. It is a topic people can study extensively (independent of language) and build expertise in. You can't say that about min/max...

Answer (score 7):

Can you be an expert in it? No. Does searching for the tag work better than searching titles or bodies? No.

Comment: Did you answer the question? No.

Comment: @corsiKa Since when did answer on meta answer the question? Since when *were* there questions anyway?

Answer (score 7):

I could've sworn I'd answered this same request before, but I can't find it anywhere...

So far as I can tell, these tags are *generally* used properly: to reflect specific concepts present in the question. There are a bunch more like this. At worst, they're not doing any harm, and perhaps for a few people with specialized interests they're helpful.

Comment: So I see you declined this when the top voted answer for was +43 and the top voted answer against at +7. Would the answer to [my question here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256149/when-should-a-burninate-request-be-actioned?lq=1) be that they should never be actioned until an employee has responded either way then?

Comment: I missed that question, @Martin; there are at least two others along the same lines though, so I'm doing a pass on pending requests here to compile some guidance for folks posting these; right now, the criteria are all over the map, and that's just a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 4):

These are useful tags. They refer to a specific, very common, algorithmic problem which beginners often need help with. Combining this tag with a tag for the name of a language is probably a useful thing to do if you don't know how to calculate max and min in that language. Similarly there is a tag for 'sorting'.

Max and min probably seem trivial if you have written them a few times, but there are several places someone could go wrong with edge cases (empty lists), hidden assumptions (that values fall in a certain range) or special cases (max over weird containers, values which aren't obvious to order, eg `null`).

The fact that there are a large number of questions for these tags suggests that they are worth keeping. The fact that they have a small number of followers doesn't prove much - their main purpose is search rather than catering to 'max enthusiasts' and 'min aficionados'.

Comment: But are these cases special enough to warrant their own tag? Tagging with `max` won't help getting answers on how to implement it in any language - why isn't it enough to put this in the question title? By your logic, everything that's commonly used in beginner excercises should have its own tag; hello-world, fibs, factorials, whatever. And "their main purpose is search" is just plain wrong - first, the officially stated purpose of tags is to connect experts (==followers) with questions; second, searching a tag with such a vast range of languages doesn't exactly seem useful.

Comment: @l4mpi 1. It seems to me that [hello-world] and [fibonacci] tags would be very useful, for the same reasons. But I am not arguing for tags to be added, just for two tags which are used *not to be removed*, which surely has a smaller burden of proof. 2. I said that the main purpose of *these* tags is search. You can search for combinations of tags, you know.

Comment: We had this discussion about [hello-world](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254240/is-the-hello-world-tag-useful) already, it's gone and it should definitely stay this way. And you still fail to say how exactly a tag would be more useful for searching than just searching for the words min or max as part of the question title, combined with a language tag. Even if a tag would somehow significantly improve searching here, it's not like searching for min/max is hard to begin with; or that most people asking these questions even know how to use the search correctly...

Comment: The usefulness of a tag as compared to a title should be obvious. Do you search for 'max' as a whole word (thus missing 'maximum'), or as part of a word (thus including various false positives)? Are you aware of the philosophical objection to 'tagging in titles'?

Comment: No, the usefulness is not obvious - you can't even back up your assumption that people actually search for it **as a tag** as opposed to a plaintext word (not sure if we could find proof via the data explorer). And of course I'm aware of the _ongoing discussion_ about tags in titles - these tags are part of the problem, how would you title a question about implementing `max` that is tagged `max` as well? Also, at the very least it is pure noise to have distinct tags for min and max as these are an extremely similar concept.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your last point. A single tag for [min_and_max] would make much more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we're going to keep them... (I'm not quite decided on that, but this should be a decent compromise one way or the other)

Do we really need **both**?

Is finding the minimum all the different from finding the maximum?

Shouldn't we perhaps make both a synonym of something else (["extremum"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima), I guess)?

Comment: If I was searching for all question pertaining to min or max, I certainly would not search for extremum! I know it's technically correct, but it just wouldn't enter into my head.

Comment: This is exactly what was proposed in the comments by @NiettheDarkAbsol -- see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255672/2235132

Comment: @DMK If they're synonyms, you can still just search for [min] or [max]. Feel free to make a better suggestion if you have one (I don't).

Comment: @Dukeling I guess that didn't enter into my head either :)

Comment: make `min` and `max` as tag synonyms for `extremum`?

Answer (score -6):

Yes.

Most programming languages have special methods/functions for finding min and max, sometimes within all sorts of collections. Why not have a tag to cover this area of programming?

Finding a maximum is not always as easy as it sounds, especially when dealing with complex structures, and in languages that might not have the [compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compare) concept.

Comment: Imho, the question here is not if it is trivial (i agree, it is not) but if there is any use in having a tag for it. So i believe the question to be whether it is likely that a question either gets answered faster or better due to being tagged max. What i believe is extremely unlikely as noone would search for them specifically. Or if it allows the question to be found easier by someone looking for an answer later. And i highly doubt that it helps in that case over searching for the language in question and the word max. However, there is also an "output" tag...