# When should a burninate request be actioned?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

The question [Do we really need [max] and [min]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255631/73226) currently has the top two voted answers "for" the burnination at +34 and +27.

The next answer is against the idea and is on +12.

Is that a significant enough majority to start the burnination? If not what criteria should be used?

Comment: If you count votes on the question, 48 for and 9 against.

Comment: It is mostly empty talk, Jeff Atwood isn't around anymore to flip the switch.  Maybe Oded, but he has to be involved.  The hired community leads are far too busy moving around leaky buckets.

Comment: I'm intrigued to see that there are folks who find the tags useful!

Comment: Writing highly upvoted rants seems to be @HansPassant 's hobby as of late...