# Will it make a [difference] if we burninate it?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/difference) tag, according to the tag wiki has two different descriptions:

1. the difference between two numbers, and
2. the things that two or more objects do not share in common.

There are only 249 questions tagged and I don't quite see how one can be an expert in differences in two numbers. The questions that don't fit the second description, don't quite fit the first description either.

Some of those questions are about date differences, which already there are two tags for that are [date-difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-difference) and [datediff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datediff) (Whether or not these two should be merged is content for a new meta post all together). So those questions should be re-tagged appropriately.

For the remaining questions, the tag should just be removed because no one can be an expert in differences in numbers in a programming language. This [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255631/do-we-really-need-max-and-min)'s principles about max and min can apply here as well. Most of the questions about differences in numbers results in the answer going something along the lines of `foobar = foo - bar;`.

For the questions that do fit the second description, a new tag, [language-specific-differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-specific-differences), a shorter [language-differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-differences) (although this may be misleading).

Comment: From tag wiki, [tag:date-difference] and [tag:datediff] refer to a function, not a general "difference between dates" (which again, may be misleading). For the last case, I agree that we may need a new tag for that, though not sure about the word. Seems like a difference between [tag:language-features] for me.

Comment: `*poke*` This is still an issue.

Comment: For that matter, I can't tell the [tag:difference] between [tag:subtract] and [tag:subtraction].

Comment: Get rid of it...

Comment: Nearly seven years later and this tag still exists with 1600+ questions. Mind-boggling