# Burninate the width and height tags

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Burninate [width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/width) and [height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/height). There are no experts for these things.
<sup><sub>*( Please no arguments like "there are measurement experts who might specialize in width"* :P *)*</sub></sup>
Searching for the tags isn't better than searching title/body, it doesn't categorize questions better.

Comment: 6887 unique questions, and it does not help on any of them! If that's not something for nuking from orbit...

Comment: Sad to say my particular expertise applies only to length and depth, so I can never answer these width and height questions.

Comment: NO `girth` tag? Everybody knows it's really the girth that matters.

Comment: Isn't [tag:height] a JavaScript library though? So is [tag:width] probably.

Answer (score 2):

## Update (15th July 2015)

After doing a bit more research I'm now fully under the impression that neither of these tags should be burninated.

1. A similar question with similar voting patterns, [Do we really need [max] and [min]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255631/do-we-really-need-max-and-min), was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) by Shog9 ♦ for the [following reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260537/1317805):

> ...as I can tell, these tags are generally used properly: to reflect specific concepts present in the question. There are a bunch more like this. At worst, they're not doing any harm, and perhaps for a few people with specialized interests they're helpful.

2. SE Meta's [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate) thread asks the following questions:

   - **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
   - **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   - **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   - **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

I feel the answer to all of the above questions is: **yes** for both the [height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/height) and [width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/width) tags. Under the above criteria there is really no need to burninate either of the tags.

---

## Original Answer

As the now-*top user* for the [height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/height) tag I'm going to defend my shiny tag. This comes after a lot of questions which previously had the tag have now had the tag removed. ["Removed the tag for burnination"](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1575141/6), for instance. This doesn't help anyone, and I'd like to keep [my pretty bronze badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4925/height?userid=1317805)* if I can.

<sup>* Which had to be re-awarded to me after someone removed the Height tag from one of the questions I'd answered. :-(</sup>

Before I continue, I'm going to quote following exerpt from the [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) page:

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.
>
> Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you.

To counter your arguments why these tags should be removed I'm going to breakdown your post:

> No experts ... it doesn't categorize questions better

I disagree with this. Height and Width may not be things which people can be experts in, per se, but they certainly do help sort related questions - and clearly a lot of people do add these tags to their questions for that very reason. If your problem is entirely height or width-related, why not add the tag in?

> searching for the tags isn't better than searching title/body

Incorrect. I personally have used the search query `[css] [height]` in the past for finding questions to answer which are explicitly about height and involve CSS. If you do a search for `[css] [height]` you'll find [1,937 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?tags=css%20height&mode=all). If you do a search instead for `[css] "height"` you'll find a mix of [over 70,000 questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D%20%22height%22) - the most voted being the answer to the question [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work); a question which is very loosely related to the concept of height, if at all.

---

If we're to burninate [height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/height) and [width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/width), we're also going to have to burninate all other conceptual tags - [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace), for instance. Are there really any whitespace experts out there?

Comment: Make a css-width tag? I do think whotespace is a bad tag.

Comment: @bjb568 In CSS `width` and `height` are actual property names. Questions concerning widths and heights may not necessarily relate to those properties, so I feel tags named Height and Width would be more appropriate in this situation.

Comment: Perhaps specific uses of width/height can be split off, but I don't see any use of a general width/height tag.