# Burn the tag at [highest] priority

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The tag [highest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highest) has no clear usage although it seems people use it in questions regarding the largest item in a set. There are currently 118 questions and almost all of them are about finding the maximum value. Many questions even have both the [max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/max) and [highest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highest) tags

IMHO we should make [highest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highest) a synonym of [max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/max)

Comment: I would even challenge the value of the [tag:max] tag in addition to this one.

Comment: @Alejandro: indeed, [Do we really need \[max\] and \[min\]?]([Do we really need \[max\] and \[min\]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255631)) is an existing discussion about that.  Making [highest] a synonym is a useful first step, though, regardless of what we eventually do to [max].

Comment: @PeterCordes merging them would be the worst option, since it would make a small tag bigger. and gives us 115 that we have to touch again.

Comment: @Braiam: Synonymizing tags doesn't "touch" the involved questions in the first place (no bumping), and the old questions keep their original tag until/unless they're edited and the edit window substitutes the synonym.  Also, I think it's unlikely that we'd decide to do something different with questions that were originally tagged [highest] from what we do with questions originally tagged [max], which is part of why I suggested it would be a useful first step regardless.  If we weren't sure they were synonyms, then yeah be cautious.

Comment: @PeterCordes The thing here is that none of them are good tags. If there's a small set of questions that can be easily found and fixed, we want to keep it that way. That's the point. Imagine that we successfully removed a tag, before it became a larger problem. We want stuff that can give endorphin when completed. Making the tag more insurmountable doesn't do that.

Comment: 9 watchers :) Ooh, I wonder what highest questions that will get posted today? I guess some people use the site while high and some while at their highest.