# Avoid creating tags, if these were deleted

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I had 1500 reputation: "Awarded At Creation Privilege: Create Tags", I created the tag [hello-world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello-world), which a moderator deleted (correctly, I must say).

When I check on Meta, to my surprise I found that the tag had been created and removed before, and I now understand the reasons for removing this bad tag:

[Is the Hello-world tag useful?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254240/is-the-hello-world-tag-useful)

but,

- Why does Stack Overflow allow creating this tag, if it had been created and deleted before?
- Can I view the list of removed tags? To avoid doing it again.

Comment: what if a tag that once was not useful becomes the name of a new language, tool, or library?

Comment: which situation involves greater effort (time) to moderators ? (delete tags or reopen tags)

Comment: No clue. I guess they found that delete tags was better than the alternative.

Comment: I think the underlying problem is that a moderator did this.  They can't ban tags, only SE employees can do that.  Examples of banned tags would be [programming] and [best-practices].

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, it wasn't a moderator that burned [hello-world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello-world) when you created it, it was me. Note that it had burned previously via [this older MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254240/is-the-hello-world-tag-useful?lq=1).

---

That said, there are two different concepts:

- **Burninating** a tag involves removing the tag from all posts that have the tag and/or deleting the questions with the tag so that the tag no longer exists and requires a 1500 rep user to make the tag again.
- **Blacklisting** a tag is a *Stack Overflow staff* only action that prevents tags from being used in the tag box. It makes a red box appear that says "you may not use this tag".

  - Note that this does not necessarily mean the tag is burninated - a tag can be blacklisted and still exist on older questions, see below:

There has been a large push from many people, myself included, to make blacklisting tags easier. Currently, the burnination process has very recently been changed as part of this concept: [Make it easier to prevent new questions being added in a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307068/1768232)

We recently had this conversation in [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4025543#4025543):

> durron597: @Shog9 I mean, I can't ever see a reason for [legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legal) or [software-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-tools) to come back one day. I've always wondered why tags get approved for burnination but not for blacklisting. Can you explain?
> Shog9: @durron597 historical reasons, mostly
> Shog9: blacklisting prevents submission of any edits containing the tag
> Shog9: **so once it's blacklisted, you cannot edit questions in the tag without removing it**

Because the possible consequences for blacklisting, and the fact that it must go via staff (a regular ♦ moderator cannot do it), it simply doesn't happen that often.

There's also the possibility that someone will, say, make a hello-world library or a hello-world language and then the tag actually will be valid.

---

As far as *viewing* the blacklist, I'm reasonably certain you cannot, but since a box will pop up saying the tag is not allowed when asking / editing a question, you shouldn't need one.

In any event, the blacklist is actually a regular expression, not simple list of tags, so it's probably more complicated than you suspect.

Comment: So I guess I'd better think of a different name for my in-the-works jQuery hello-world library then....

Comment: @outflak simple, just tag it is [jQuery-hello-world-library-please-don't-burninate]

Comment: Our room triggers on burninate... @Trobbins